# Differential equation/Grönwall's inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

I have 2 Integral equation: $$y(t)= e + \int_1^t y(s) + e^s ds$$
                            $$z(t)= e + \int_1^t sin z(s) + e^s ds$$

The solution for the first one ist $y(t)= te^t$
Now I want to calculate $$|y(t) -z(t)|= |\int_1^t y(s) + e^s -sin z(s) - e^s ds |\leq \int_1^t |(y(s) -sin z(s) ds|  $$
Now I can use the following $| (y(t) -sin z(t) | \leq \frac{|y|^3}{6}$, so I get:
$$|y(t) -z(t)|\leq \int_1^t \frac{|y|^3}{6} ds =  \int_1^t \frac{|e^tt|^3}{6} ds$$

How can I apply  Grönwall's inequality now?

Comment: How did you get the inequality $|y(t)-\sin z(t)|\le \frac{|y(t)|^3}6$? Did you miss the term $|\sin y(t)-\sin z(t)|\le |y(t)-z(t)|$? And $|\sin y - y|\le \frac{|y|^3}6$ is only valid for $|y|^2<20$ by the Leibniz test for alternating series.

Comment: No the inequality was given in this form.

Comment: While it might be ultimately true, the present steps do not support this inequality. And in the final equation there is nothing left to apply Grönwall to, the right side is a fixed function. This alone should tell you that something might be wrong.

Comment: Ok I see that, The task said, that I have to to estimate the difference $ |y(t)-z(t)|$ using the solution y(t)  and Grönwall's inequality with g(t), who can be calculated easier.

Comment: Therefore  I can use$| (y(t) -sin z(t) | \leq \frac{|y|^3}{6}$, How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $|y-\sin y|\le \frac{|y|^3}6$, you get that
$$
|y-\sin z|\le|\sin y-\sin z|+|y-\sin y|\le \min(2,|y-z|)+\frac{|y|^3}6.
$$
By the Grönwall inequality, the exact solution of
$$
u(t)=\int_1^t\left(u(s)+\frac{s^3e^{3s}}6\right)\,ds\iff
u'(t)=u(t)+\frac{t^3e^{3t}}6,~~u(1)=0,
$$
will be an upper bound for $|z(t)-y(t)|\le u(t)$. This gives
$$
(e^{-t}u(t))'=\frac{t^3e^{2t}}6\implies u(t)=\frac{e^{3t} (t-1)(4t^2-2t+4)}{48}+\frac{e^{3t}-e^{2+t}}{48}
$$

Comment: I don't get where and how you apply the Grönwall inequality?

Comment: One interpretation of Grönwall is that the equality solution, here $u$, of the differential inequality is an upper bound of the function in the inequality.

Comment: The  Grönwall inequality that we only know  says: If $\phi(t) \leq \alpha(t) + \int_a^t \phi(s) ds $    $ \Rightarrow$ $\phi(t) \leq \alpha(t) + \int_a^t e^{t-s} \alpha(s)$ What is also $\alpha(t)$ in my case?

Comment: Here you get $α(t)=\int_1^t\frac{s^3e^{3s}}6\,ds$. By partial integration, you will get exactly my terms. Note that the right side is the exact solution of $u'=α'+u\iff(u-α)'=(u-α)+α\iff (e^{-t}(u-α))'=e^{-t}α$.

Comment: $$
u(t)=\int_1^t\left(u(s)+\frac{s^3e^{3s}}6\right)\,ds $$ I thought $ u(t)=min( 2, |u(t)|) $. Why is $u(t) $equal to  $\int....$

Comment: At the end why do you multiply u(t) with $e^{-t}$

Comment: I left out the minimum, as $\min(2,|y-z|)\le|y-z|$ and trying to find the point where $u(t)=2$ looks ugly. So take the larger bound, in any case it is a rapidly increasing bound. // $e^{-t}$ is the integrating factor in $u'(t)=u(t)+r(t)$.

Comment: When you take the 2, then you wouldn't  need Grönwall?

Comment: I get, when I write this in my form: $$ u(t) \leq \int_1^t \frac{s^3 3^{3s}}{6} ds + \int_1^t e^{t-s}(  \int_1^t \frac{k^3 3^{3k}}{6} dk) ds$$

Comment: Is this right in this form?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Now apply partial integration to reduce the double integral to a simple integral. // Yes, for the branch where $u(t)\ge 2$ one does not need Grönwall, only simple integration. As I said, the problem is to find the boundary point between the two branches to get the correct integration constant for the second branch.

Comment: Thank you :)   "As I said, the problem is to find the boundary point between the two branches to get the correct integration constant for the second branch" What do you mean by that?

Comment: In $u'(t)=\min(2,u(t))+r(t)$, the function $u$ is monotonically increasing. The switch in the minimum operation happens at the point $t_*$ where $u$ has climbed from $0$ to $2$. In that segment, $u'=u+r$. After that point, $u'=2+r$ with $u(t_*)=2$ as initial condition. Thus you have to solve $u(t_*)=2$ for the expression of the first segment.

Comment: Ok I think I got that. How do you know, that u is monotonically increasing?